# How can I spread out randomly located images in js?

Tags: javascript, random

I am randomly placing images on a canvas in javascript. The problem is that I want to minimize stacking but not prevent it. I would like to see the behavior where if there is enough images to fit on the canvas without overlapping, they wont. However, I want the images to not appear ordered. Any ideas?

Comment: Did you check out jQuery? There are a few plug-ins that would help you

Comment: Im using jQuery, but Im not familiar with any plugin to do this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up going with an inverted normal distribution which will likely leave space in the center to allow images to be viewed while images on the outside are more likely to be stacked.

Answer (score 4):

You could place them evenly, then randomly move them a bit... somthing like this:

```
var w = 200, h = 150, leftOffset = 60, topOffset = 30, leftDeviation = 90, topDeviation = 60
for(i=0;i<5;i++)
    $('<div />').css({
        left:(i*w+leftOffset+Math.round(Math.random()*leftDeviation)),
        top:(topOffset+Math.round(Math.random()*topDeviation)),
        opacity:.6,width:w,height:h,backgroundColor:'red',position: 'absolute'}).appendTo('body')
```

Demo here: http://jsfiddle.net/y2hdE/

This includes grid layout: http://jsfiddle.net/y2hdE/1/

Once you have placed all the images using a formula similar to mine, you could then randomly select what spot the photo drops into, so all the positions are pre-determined, but the order is random.

Comment: the major problem with even placement is that it doesnt support unlimited elements, another problem is that it doesnt allow an image to overlap with two others nicely

Answer (score 0):

How far are you in your approach?
You say that you can, but don't want to prevent stacking. Why don't you use your algorithm, add the prevention and do some exceptions based on a random number?